# SDWebImage With Custom UITableView Cell Image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, sdwebimage

I am trying to use `SDWebImage` library with a custom `UITableViewCell`. Below is the method that is downloading the images from the web service:

```
- (void) downloadThumbnails:(NSURL *)finalUrl
{
    SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
    [manager downloadWithURL:finalUrl
                     options:0
                    progress:nil
                   completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished)
     {
         if (image)
         {
             // do something with image
             // THERE I HAVE TO ASSIGN the property "thumbnail" with the "image"
             // So it can be used by the tableview controller class
         }
     }];

}
```

The above code is in a separate file named `RSSItem`. While my `UITableViewController` class has the following `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ItemsCell";

    ItemsViewCell *cell = (ItemsViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    RSSItem *item = [[channel items] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    cell.titleLabel.text = [item title];
    cell.creatorLabel.text = [item creator];
    cell.pubTimeLabel.text = [item pubTime];
    cell.thumbContainer.image = [item thumbnail];

    return cell;
}
```

Can somebody point out how can i configure the if (image) inside downloadThumbnails method? I just need to assign "image" to the property "thumbnail", how can i do that?

Comment: Please show your try code when download complete?

Comment: @NAQ i didn't get what you asked for. But i have added an update how it used to work without SDWebImage. Hope it answers what you asked for

Comment: Where do you store URL of each images?

Comment: @NAQ that i am passing to this method with the argument name "finalUrl"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you have already used the right method to download images asynchronously using SDWebImage. All you need to do is to set the thumbnail property to the "image". Here is how you can do it:

```
- (void) downloadThumbnails:(NSURL *)finalUrl
{
    SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
    [manager downloadWithURL:finalUrl
                     options:0
                    progress:nil
                   completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished)
     {
         if (image)
         {
             [self setThumbnail:image];
         }
     }];

}
```