# SDWebImage images loading out of order

Tags: ios, objective-c

My images aren't loading in the right order, even the first time the app loads the list.

If I'm doing something blatantly wrong here, let me know?

```
- (DetailTableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    DetailTableViewCell *cell = (DetailTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"QueueCell"];

    cell.textLabel.text = _tracks[indexPath.row][@"title"];
    if(_thumbnails.count > indexPath.row)
    {
        [cell.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_thumbnails[indexPath.row]]];
    }
    cell.upVoteButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.downVoteButton.tag = indexPath.row;

    NSString* rating = _tracks[indexPath.row][@"userRating"];
    if(!(rating == (id)[NSNull null] || rating.length == 0))
    {
        if([rating isEqualToString:@"1"])
        {
            cell.upVoteButton.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"UpArrowColor"];
            cell.downVoteButton.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DownArrow"];
        }
        else if([rating isEqualToString:@"-1"])
        {
            cell.downVoteButton.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DownArrowColor"];
            cell.upVoteButton.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"UpArrow"];
        }
        else
        {
            cell.downVoteButton.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DownArrow"];
            cell.upVoteButton.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"UpArrow"];
        }
    }

    return cell;
}
```

The images load randomly, one happens to be in the right place this time.

[image: Screenshot, showing out of order]

Comment: I've seen this, but it didn't help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18342172/load-images-using-sdwebimage-in-order?rq=1

Comment: Also tried this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17078658/sdwebimage-with-custom-uitableview-cell-image?rq=1

Same issue.

Comment: Are you cancelling the web image load when the cell is reused?

Comment: How would I know when the cell gets re-used?

Comment: Looks like you subclassed the table view cell.  Override the `-(void)prepareForReuse` in the cell and add `[[self imageView] sd_cancelCurrentImageLoad];`